# Exception message while sending an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Exception:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not
>   authenticated

I am not using `Defaultcredentials`, so I set `client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;`
Also, I provided valid email id and password, host name and port number; however, I am 
still getting the same Exception. How can I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
public void SendCustomerForgotPassword(string mailTo, string forgotUserId, string forgotPassword) 
{ 
    string mailSubject = "", mailBody = "";
    mailSubject = ""; 
    StringBuilder sbMailBody = new StringBuilder(); 
    sbMailBody.AppendLine("Welcome to *****,"); 
    sbMailBody.AppendLine("\r"); 
    mailBody = sbMailBody.ToString(); 
    SetSmtpClient(mailTo, mailSubject, mailBody); 
}




    private void SetSmtpClient(string recipients, string subject, string body)
    {
        string EmailFrom = "here set an email id";
        string EmailFromPassword = "set password";

        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(EmailFrom, EmailFromPassword); 
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(); 
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
        client.EnableSsl = true; 
        client.Host = "pod51018.outlook.com"; 
        client.Port = 587; 
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
        client.Credentials = credentials; 
        client.Send(EmailFrom, recipients, subject, body);
    }
```

Comment: @Manjusha please edit your question and put the formatted code there, rather than a comment.

Comment: Make sure you change that password so people don't use your sever as a relay. You wouldn't want your server to become blacklisted.

Comment: where is SmtpClient object initialization?

Comment: client.Host = "pod51018.outlook.com";
            client.Port = 587;

Comment: any errors are there in the above code plz let me know

Comment: Why am getting this error please let me know

Comment: refer the link below it may help http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/159/t/18337.aspx

Comment: have to add Encryption method in my code

Comment: just set EnableSsl =True and i see you have already done that

Comment: or for testing create a gmail acccount and try.See whether it works

Comment: @Manjusha check the updated link and follow those steps to get your account setting.Check whether the port ,encryption method everything matches

Comment: @karthi-client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Host = "pod51018.outlook.com";
            client.Port = 995;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

Comment: i have already added all those

Comment: better try a google account .. so that you can make sure your code is fine

Comment: working well with google credentials

Comment: @Manjusha then make sure all the credentials port you pass for the another account is correct.it seems there is some issue with that configuration

Comment: @karthi-ok i will check that .Can u please suggest me how to set email credentials in my web.config.From there i have to access the emailid and password in my cs

Comment: add this in the config section of your webconfig <appSettings><add key="username" value="test@gmail.com"/></appSettings> to access in cs file use     string uname= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["username"];

Answer (score 0):

Just like the message states, you're not authenticated.

In your code:

```
string EmailFrom = "";
string EmailFromPassword = "";

        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(EmailFrom, EmailFromPassword);
```

If this is your exact code - you're passing an empty username and password..

Comment: No am sending my credentials emailid and password

Comment: @Manjusha - So in your code EmailFrom and EmailFromPassword have the correct username/password inside them?

Comment: @Blachshma - Previously it was worked now its showing that exception

Comment: Did you try switching to port 995 instead of 587?

Comment: @Blachshma- No i will try once

Comment: @Blachshma - when i switched to port 995 instead of of 587 it shows an Exception of Failure Sending a mail

Comment: What else did it write? What exactly was the failure?

Comment: nothing else i was changed only port number as you told before

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the following details are correct (as in the details shown on your Office 365 panel)

1. Host Name
2. E-Mail Address
3. Password

The code appears good (assuming your actually passing an address/password **since it's a blank string in your code**) so it's likely an issue in your settings.